# snap versions don't match

Tags: 16.04, server, snap

After a fresh Ubuntu server install I've done a:

```
snap install core
```

and the result was:

> Apr 27 07:10:07 n snap[11059]: cmd.go:114: DEBUG: not restarting into "/snap/core/current/usr/bin/snap" ([VERSION=2.23.6 2.23.6]): older than "/usr/bin/snap" (2.24.1)

Can I solve this?

Comment: yeah, I have the same problem

Comment: tiago, janek, is this a problem? I mean: that message isn't an error, merely informative (you shouldn't see it unless you turn on debug, or look in journalctl). I'm assuming something went wrong that makes you think it's an error?

Answer (score 2):

That message (which you wouldn't normally see unless you either enabled debug, or went looking in the system journal) means that the snapd package in your distribution is newer than the core snap in your system. This is not normally a problem (it would be if we didn't detect it, which is why we log it when we do); `snapd` and `snap` (and `snap-confine`, and etc.) will do the right thing in this scenario, and most likely you'll soon have a refreshed core snap that will bring everything back into sync.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm that this doesn't affect functionality.
I've started debuging because I couldn't make snaps work on a VPS, but I've figured it out that the problem was the images used by the VPS provider.